# Submitting data from textarea by hitting "Enter"

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have dynamic web page with JS. There is a `<textarea>` and a *Send* button, but no `<form>` tags. How do I make *Submit* button fire and the `<textarea>` get cleared when *Enter* is pressed in the `<textarea>`?

Comment: I am sorry for misleading you. I read textarea but think input type="text" ...... Removed my crappy answer :)

Comment: People are asking why not use a input[text] instead of textarea.  For me, the reason is I want to allow user to enter only one line of text, but I want the text to wrap onto multiple lines.  The input[text] does not wrap

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use an keyup handler for the textarea (although I would advise against it*).

```
[SomeTextarea].onkeyup = function(e){
  e = e || event;
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    // start your submit function
  }
  return true;
 }
```

*Why not use a text input field for this? Textarea is escpecially suited for multiline input, a text input field for single line input. With an enter handler you criple the multiline input. I remember using it once for a XHR (aka AJAX) chat application (so the textarea behaved like an MSN input area), but re-enabled multiline input using the CTRL-enter key for new lines. May be that's an idea for you? The listener would be extended like this:

```
[SomeTextarea].onkeyup = function(e){
  e = e || event;
  if (e.keyCode === 13 && !e.ctrlKey) {
    // start your submit function
  }
  return true;
 }
```

Comment: Looks nice, thanks. What do you need the line *e = e || event;* for?

Comment: @Alex: firefox, opera, and safari (and other browsers that embed webkit) pass events as an argument to the event handler, but IE does not.  In IE the event is a property on the global object.  Happily the semantics of || in JS make it really clean to work around this.


In JS the result of the expression `a || b` will be either the value of `a`, or if `a` is considered false, the result will be `b`.  So in this case `e = e || event` will either assign `e` to itself if the event is passed as an argument, or it will set `e` to the of `event`, thus letting this code work in all browsers.

Answer (score 15):

Hitting Enter in a `textarea` inserts a line break, rather than submitting the parent form; this would't work in that fashion even with regular form tags.

It would be inadvisable to attempt to work around this behaviour, as it would violate the user's expectation of how text area controls behave, both in other web sites, and in other applications on their platform.

Comment: ++for the "inadvisable" paragraph. Always knowing what the enter key will do in a website textarea is one of the many little consistencies that i miss when using other GUIs.

Comment: although i totally agree with your advice, the question at hand is very precisely formulated and requires rather a real answer than a good advice. +1 still, but couldn't you advise on how to attach some sort of keyListener to the textarea to submit the form on Enter as asked for? I am rather interested...

Comment: I upvoted this answer a long time ago, but there are cases where the user is not really aware that he's typing into a textarea. Consider the input line of facebook's chat for example. It starts as a single line and expands vertically as the user types more. It's absolutely reasonable for users to expect it to submit on enter.

Comment: This is exactly my use case as well in researching which led me to this post.

Comment: This absolutely depends on how the textarea is used. For instance, here on StackOverflow, pressing enter or return in the comment-box, will submit the comment.

Comment: This is fairly common and is not inadvisable or unexpected behavior at all when combined with Shift+Enter for a newline.

Answer (score 13):

@Shog9 suggested that I copy my answer to a duplicated version of this question:
One issue this ignores is users running input method (editors) -- eg. non-latin text entry.  The IME I am familiar with is the Kotoeri Hiragana IM on OSX, but there are numerous others both for japanese (Kotoeri alone has multiple different input modes, and there's at least one other major one called ATOK), in addition to modes for hangul, traditional and simplified Chinese, as well as numerous other less well known languages.  And these input methods exist on all major platforms (esp. Win, Mac, and Linux).

The problem that they introduce from the point of view of code similar to what you're attempting is that the exact physical key presses does not necessarily correspond to the actual input that the user is entering.

For example typing the sequence of characters `toukyou<enter>` under hiragana by default will produce the string `とうきょう`, note that there is no `<enter>` in the resultant text because enter confirms the composed text.  But in addition to this the actual sequence of characters that appears changes as the input is typed:

```
t // t
と // to
とう // tou
とうk // touk
とうky // touky
とうきょ // toukyo
とうきょう // toukyou
```

If memory serves when I implemented this in webkit it was necessary to make the keyCode be 229 on keyDown for all keys typed in an IME (for compat with IE) -- but I cannot recall what the behaviour of keyUp is.

It's also worth noting that in some IMEs you won't necessarily receive keydowns, keypress, or keyup.  Or you will receive multiple.  Or they're all sent together at the end of input.

In general this is a very... unclean... portion of the DOM event implementations currently.

Comment: It shows that lots of folks take the fact the languages they speak have one character per keystroke for granted. That's what I did.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

In Javascript:

```
function isEnterPressed(e){
var keycode=null;
if (e!=null){
    if (window.event!=undefined){
        if (window.event.keyCode) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
        else if (window.event.charCode) keycode = window.event.charCode;
    }else{
        keycode = e.keyCode;
    }
}
return (keycode == 13);}
```

In html:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="if(isEnterPressed(event)){/*do something*/}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The textarea is for allowing users to enter multiple lines of text so, pressing enter would only insert a new line in the text. Use normal text field instead if you want that behavior