# How to submit textareas on ENTER/RETURN keydown

Tags: javascript

In an input box if you press RETURN/ENTER you submit the form. In a textarea pressing RETURN produces a line-break. How do you make a  that on RETURN keydown instead of producing a line-break submits the form and in SHIFT+RETURN produces the line-break? (Like fb and other sites do)

Is there some way to do it with just HTML? If not how can it be done with JS?

This is what I am trying right now:

```
$('#conversationForm textarea').keydown(function(e) {
    e = e || event;
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        $("#conversationForm").submit();
        return false;
        }
    });
```

However when I haven't been able to prevent the line-break from happening. (If you press RETURN the line break is visible before submitting.)

Comment: Will definitely need javascript. The how-to is answered [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789701/submitting-data-from-textarea-by-hitting-enter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery, and similar to the other answers, but including your request to make shift not submit but just do a line break

```
$("#mytextarea").keypress(function() {
  if(event.which == 13 && !event.shiftKey)
  {
      //submit your form here  i.e. form.submit();
  }
});​
```

Here if shift is pressed, it won't submit and just give you a line-break.

Comment: I'm still having the problem of the line-break being visible before submitting. I updated the question to show what my code looks right now.

Comment: hmm...not sure.  In my testing, the return false nullifies the line-break.  So I don't see it before the form submits.  Try flipping to keypress?  Even remove the event and verify that the return false does prevent the line-break on the browser you're testing with.  I'm using Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [Submitting data from textarea by hitting "Enter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789701/submitting-data-from-textarea-by-hitting-enter) as you can see there

```
[SomeTextarea].onkeyup = function(e){
  e = e || event;
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    // start your submit function
  }
  return true;
 }
```

would be the solution you look for

Comment: I added part of the code from another answer to take into account the shift key. However the line break is still visible (it happens before submitting the form) What can be done to prevent this? Also I changed keyup for keydown since line-breaks are executed onkeydown

Comment: return false instead of true and also you can try e.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0):

Attach a `keydown` event listener. If `event.keyCode || event.which` evaluates to 13 (or 10, to be safe) then the Enter key was pressed so you can submit the form using the form's `submit` method.